# Studying for Discrete Math finals and trying to asnwer these questions on sets need help

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am studying for my final exam for discrete and i am doing some exaple quesion on sets.

Here is a picture of the question:
[image]

Here is my attempt as solving them:

Problem 1:

D = {1,3}

E = {5,7,11}

F = {1,2,3,5,7,9,11}

Problem 2:

D = {1,3,4,6,8}

E = {5,7,11}

Problem 3:

D = {2,7,11}

E = {3,5}

A = {2,4,6,8,10,12}

Can anybody tell me if I'm correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All correct, except for:

Problem 1

$E = A' \cup C = \{ 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 \}$. Your answer is for $A' \cap C$

Problem 3:

$E = A' \cup B = \{ 1,3,5,7,9,10,11 \}$.  Again, you evaluated the intersection instead of he union

Comment: @PhillipMc Sure, no problem!